# Train LSTM with custom padding in each batch size

Tags: keras, lstm, word-embedding, zero-padding

I am training a RNN for text classification. I want to train the model with a batch size `X`. However, for each batch, I want to create a zero padding where `word_padding_length = maximum string length in each batch - current_word_length`. I have tried search but was not able to find anything related to this. This should happen during when I fit the model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you cannot change the input tensor shape during the training process. In your case, you want to have:
 `(batch_size, len1, num_features) -> (batch_size, len2, num_features)` for each steps.

You can have sth similar to this:

```
from keras.models import Model
from keras.layers import Input, LSTM

x = Input(shape=(None,128))
hidden = LSTM(32)(x)
model = Model(x, hidden)

for batch in batch_lst:
     model.train_on_batch(batch)
```

Noted that `Input` has shape of (**None**, 128), which means **variable batch_size, variable time_steps, and fixed num_feature=128**

Moreover, you might consider using [masking layer](https://keras.io/zh/layers/core/#masking) to ignore all your padding values, so that you can have one tensor input for whole training set while the model performance is not affected by padding.